# Intermittent slowness in responses from vert.x based web server

Tags: vert.x

I have a vertx webserver running on a 1x8g machine. It has about 15 routes mapped, 5 of which are blocking and 10 are non blocking. These are all part of one standard verticle that my app comprises of. The non blocking handlers just open an http connection to another downstream system ( all of which are very fast - elastic search / cached data APIs ). Some of the blocking handlers do take a bit of time - anywhere between 3 and 9 seconds depending on the time of the day - these also call an external system.

The API response time for my non blocking handlers are usually in the 400ms-600ms range. Occasionally, I see the response times spiking up to over 2 seconds and sometimes all the way up to 12 seconds. I'm not sure what is causing this. Is it the combination of blocking vs nonblocking handlers in the same verticle. 
What is the best way to diagnose the root cause here ?

Comment: When I say routes are blocking/non blocking, I meant they are mapped to blocking/nonblocking handlers respectively.

Comment: Welcome to stoackoverflow. Your question will be difficult to answer, without further insights. You should try to connect something like [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) to your process, and take some thread dumps when the problems occur. Also have a look at [Vert.x Metrics](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-dropwizard-metrics/java/).

Comment: When you say `1x8g machine`, do you mean that it's single core CPU?

Comment: Intermittent latency spikes usually come from 1/ GC pauses 2/ queuing. By default the Vert.x worker pool has a size of 20 so you have a big machine you might increase it. You can also activate metrics to check if the worker pool queue is not growing much when you have latency spikes.

Comment: By the way, There is a non blocking [Elastic Search](https://github.com/reactiverse/elasticsearch-client) client and non blocking [Web Client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/). So you might not need to use blocking route handlers.